# Know which specific rows are locked in a KEY X lock?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, locking

I'm investigating a lock issue on a query I have and I already can see some KEY locks. By joining with sys.partitions and sys.indexes I know what's the index it's doing the lock but what I wanted now is to dig even further and really know which records are in that specific partition of the index. (basically what records are effectively locked by X lock)

Is there a way to know this?

Comment: Please check this answer. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257575/looking-up-which-records-correspond-to-a-specific-resource-description-in-dm-t?rq=1

Comment: What query do you have so far?